# Custom search suggestions using Appcompat v7

Tags: android, material-design, searchview, android-appcompat

Somebody asked that the default search suggestions do not match with the material branded theme and the app looks odd while getting hints using default Search View.

So I want to share how to get custom suggestions using default Appcompat v7 library.

you will get this type of suggessions...

[image: Custom Suggestions]

Self explanatory code is not explained.

**Best to use with material design**

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I am using my own search suggestions...**

This is my `CountriesFragment` file that just show all country name in suggestions.

The trick here is that I am providing custom View to Suggestion list to show.

```
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CountriesFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean mSearchCheck;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    public static final String TEXT_FRAGMENT = "TEXT_FRAGMENT";
    public static final String CITY_NAME = "cityName";
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewGroup mainContainer;

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica",
            "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados",
            "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil",
            "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
            "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros",
            "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus",
            "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea",
            "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana",
            "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada",
            "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
            "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
            "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan",
            "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique",
            "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco",
            "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria",
            "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines",
            "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia",
            "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore",
            "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka",
            "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic",
            "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia",
            "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
            "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)",
            "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
    };

    public static CountriesFragment newInstance(String text) {
        CountriesFragment mFragment = new CountriesFragment();
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString(TEXT_FRAGMENT, text);
        mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadHints();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries, container, false);
        mInflater = inflater;
        mainContainer = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        //rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
        searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));

        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
                .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nliveo_white));


        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQuerySearchView);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(onQuerySuggestion);

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(true);

        mSearchCheck = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_add:
                addCountry();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_search:
                mSearchCheck = true;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void addCountry() {
        final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.country_row, mainContainer, false);
        final TextView countryName = (TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        countryName.setText(COUNTRIES[(int) (Math.random() * COUNTRIES.length)]);


        final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);
        final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_out);
        fadeIn.setFillAfter(false);
        fadeOut.setFillAfter(false);

        final ImageButton closeButton = (ImageButton) newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mainContainer.removeView(newView);
                    }
                }, fadeOut.getDuration());
            }
        });

        mainContainer.addView(newView, 0);
        newView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }

    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQuerySearchView = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mSearchCheck = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            if (mSearchCheck) {
                // implement your search here
                giveSuggestions(query);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void giveSuggestions(String query) {
        final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, CITY_NAME});
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNTRIES.length; i++) {
            if (COUNTRIES[i].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                cursor.addRow(new Object[]{i, COUNTRIES[i]});
        }
        mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }

    private SearchView.OnSuggestionListener onQuerySuggestion = new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void loadHints() {
        final String[] from = new String[]{CITY_NAME};
        final int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.hint_row,
                null,
                from,
                to,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    }
}
```

here is the `hint_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@color/nliveo_white"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:alpha="0.7" />
```

Simple menu file having SearchView. `menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/add"/>

</menu>
```